# Is double code avoidable when working with .subscribe() in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

Scenario:

- User is on a page and selects items which he wants in his shoppingcart
- Items are put into a (global) service
- As soon as the user enters the shoppingcart he sees all his items (which are loaded into the component via service)

Problem:

- If the user reloads the shoppingcart, all items are gone

Solution:

- All items are stored via persistence store and will be called ONLY if the user reloads the site

Process:

For getting the items after a site reload I'm subscribing to a service which collects all items from the persistence store.
The code for setting the items is nearly the same for when the user enters the shopping cart (either via reload or via direct navigation from within the application) as a subscription is only triggered after a site reload.

Example code:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        // We need the double code here because:
        // 1. The normal code is for normal navigation of the user (e.g.   from the home component to the shopping cart).
        //    The shopping cart is already filled with items
    this.shoppingCart = this.shoppingcartService.shoppingCart;

       // 2. The user reloads the site (or returns later after having it closed) and the shopping cart is filled (in the background)
       //    from the persistance store and emitted to all listeners of the application.
       this.shoppingcartEmitter = this.shoppingcartService.shoppingCartEmitter.subscribe( shoppingcart => {
        this.shoppingCart = shoppingcart;
    });
}
```

That's a simplified version but one can see that I need two lines for the same behavior.

Question:

Is there any possibility to avoid the double code?

My problem is that I need to work with the items in the shoppingcart and I would have to write code for working with the shoppingcart inside AND outside of the subscription.

Comment: Why not change the service so that it persists the selected items in the cart to [local storage or session storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)? When the service initializes it would check the storage and load the items if there were any. Then the items will not be lost in the event of a page refresh.

Comment: Yes session storage would (in that case) solve my problem. But I was wondering if there's another solution or best practice which could be added here - In case a session storage is not helping.

Comment: I would just always subscribe to the emitter. You can return a new observable that returns a result directly in the service using `Observable.of` if no trip to a store is needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to merge this two things together

```
this.shoppingcartEmitter = this.shoppingcartService.shoppingCartEmitter.subscribe( shoppingcart => {
    this.shoppingCart = shoppingcart.concat(this.shoppingcartService.shoppingCart);
}
```